# Remove unwanted character from a variable

Tags: bash, shell-script, variable, command

I've seen a few of these questions, and a few answers, but they only tells me how to echo the results to the screen, and often only refers to one character.  I need to remove the chars `',`
 and keep the answer **inside** a variable

My $var3 is:  `'/scripts/test1.sh', 'Alf Complete', '-', 'S1E1', '-', 'Episode 1', 'has', 'been', 'paused', 'hellfire', 'i', 'Engsub - Series', 'testing']`
(It's an output from another program)

This is suppose to be converted to a command, and started by using "$var4" (and should look something like this) `/scripts/test1.sh Alf Complete - S1S1 - Episode 1`...

So the question is, how can I remove the chars I don't want and keep the new data in a new variable (for example $var4)

I might add that I'm very new at both Linux and writing script.. so please, treat me as "stupid"..

**Edit 27/1**

I'm starting the script with:

```
./test1.sh 'test1','test2','test3'
```

The text behind the script is arguments left by the program that calls the script.

This is my current script

```
#!/bin/sh
# populate var0
read -r var0<<-EOF
messer  # is the program that is going to be called in the end of this script
EOF

# populate var1
read -r var1<<-EOF
 --command='m "Adam Larsson"   # this is the first arguments 
EOF
# populate argumentsreal
read -r argumentsreal<<-EOF
$@   #this is the arguments that are posted by the application that calls this script
EOF

var4="'"  # this adds the last closing '  to the code

# Join Forces
var3="$var0 $var1 $argumentsreal $var4"   
echo $var3>txt.txt # dumping result (bugcheck)
$var3  # Executing command
```

This is my code so far, my biggest issue is that when I'm running it, the program *messer* says `Invalid message - check your syntax`
But if I do `cat txt.txt` I will get the result:

**messer --command='m "Adam Larsson" testing test1,test2,test3**

If I now copy that text line, and paste it on the command line, and press enter, it works perfectly.

So, why isn't it working when I'm running it from the script?

Comment: Where does the contents of that variable come from? If it's a command and a filename, it would be better to keep them in an array. See e.g. [How can we run a command stored in a variable?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/444946)

Comment: The output is from Plex media server, I'm trying to get it to send a message via messenger instead of constantly sending email..

Comment: That link is like Russian to me.. If got the program to start, so that's not the issue, it's all the ',' that are breaking the program..

Comment: How will your script tell "Episode 1" from "Episode" "1", then?

Comment: @RudiC (didn't see your comment until now) I have no idea, but this script is only meant to send the information further but without all the '',' chars..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with `tr -d \',`; like `printf '%s\n' "$var3" |tr -d \',`; this removes all commas and single quotes from the `$var` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try `bash`'s  "Parameter Expansion: Pattern  substitution" :

```
$ echo "${var3//,}"
'/scripts/tautullimess.sh' 'Alf Complete' '-' 'S1E1' '-' 'Episode 1' 'has' 'been' 'paused' 'hellfire' 'i' 'Engsub - Series''testing']
$ echo "${var3//[\',]}"
/scripts/tautullimess.sh Alf Complete - S1E1 - Episode 1 has been paused hellfire i Engsub - Series testing]
```

Comment: Anyway to echo the result so it will be executed as a command? Or echo it to another variable?

Comment: Try `$ ${var3//[\',]}`

Comment: Yeah, oh, does that executes it as a command, I thought it only displayed the result (newbie as I wrote)

Comment: The result was: `./test1.sh: 22: ./test1.sh: Bad substitution` and I exexuted: `./test1.sh 'kalle','damke','hekl' ` one interesting thing is that when I just echoed $var3 without your modification it seemed to strip the ' signs by it self: `messer --command='m "Adam Larsson" testing kalle,damke,hekl '`

Comment: More context necessary. For me, it works (prints param count, and parameters): `${var3//[\',]}` -
 `CNT: 16, P1: Alf, P2: Complete, ALL: Alf Complete - S1E1 - Episode 1 has been paused hellfire i Engsub - Series testing]`

Comment: I've added more context (the whole script) so it will be easier to understand what I'm saying..  I added your part instead of my $var3 on the last line. However, it seems like the script removes the ' chars my it self, as you can see by the txt.txt output, or maybe .. I don't know..

Comment: You lost me. I see three commands / scripts `/scripts/tautullimess.sh`, `./test1.sh`, and `messer`, nested in an obscure way, and all different parameter sets. I'm afraid I can't help further.

Comment: Oh,, sorry will fix that. Messer is the application that  this script will execute ..